# PhantomJS & Selenium - Test calling a method from another file (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, oop, selenium, phantomjs, nullreferenceexception

I have got the following method in one file

```
public class Login
    {
         static IWebDriver driver;

          public static void LogIn(string Env, string User)
          {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Env);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000));

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@ng-model='email']")).SendKeys(User);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@ng-model='password']")).SendKeys("1234");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ui-view\"]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button")).Click();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(driver.FindElement(By.Name("some element")).Displayed,
                "Login failed, home page did not display");
        }
    }
}
```

And the test I want to call the above method from, in another:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class SmokeTest 
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            **Login.LogIn("myEnv", "user");**
        }
     }
```

I can compile with no issues but once I run Test1 I get the following message:

Automation.SmokeTest.SearchForProduct:
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Nunit points to  the `Login.LogIn("myEnv", "user");` as the source or error.

Any ideas ?

Ta.

Comment: Sorry adrianbanks, that's not the reason. If one of Xpath paths was invalid, the would have generated a Selenium Exception along the lines of 'Element not found'.

Comment: static IWebDriver driver; << NULL here

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

```
static IWebDriver driver; << NULL here
```

Long answer

You should pass driver through your Login, at your [Test]. It should be something like

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var loginPage = new Login(driver);            
        loginpage.LogIn("myEnv", "user");**
    }
```

For your Login, it could be change like following

```
public class Login
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or set driver
    /// </summary>
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    public Login(IWebDriver driver)           
    {
        this.Driver = driver;
    }

    public static void LogIn(string Env, string User)
      {
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Env);
        Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000));

        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@ng-model='email']")).SendKeys(User);
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@ng-model='password']")).SendKeys("1234");
        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"ui-view\"]/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button")).Click();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(Driver.FindElement(By.Name("some element")).Displayed,
            "Login failed, home page did not display");
    }
}
```

Comment: No Nguyen Vu Hoang, don't think that's the answer. The test itself should stay as it is (Login.LogIn("myEnv", "user");  ) even for readability reasons. Something needs to change within the Login class to allow for test to written as it is now, in a full OOP fashion.

Comment: One way would be to change the login method to looks like this: public static void LogIn(string Env, string User, IWebDriver driver) by adding passing driver as a var. This way the test stays as single liner  (Login.LogIn("myEnv", "user"); )

Comment: yes, you could do like that. However, with this approach, you need to add driver for all your methods. My approach could save you effort. However, it's your choice.

Comment: This answer is correct and it's because you are trying to reference `Login` as a static class. In this answer, you are correctly creating a new instance of `Login` and using it.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change the login method to looks like this:

```
public static void LogIn(string Env, string User, IWebDriver driver)
```

by adding passing driver as a var. This way the test stays as single liner

```
Login.LogIn("myEnv", "user");
```